# Grep the process using shell script

Tags: shell

I want to pass the output of the sql query to aix command, later the command should grep the processes until the condition met:

SAMPLE QUERY:

```
SQL> select vp.spid,vs.process,to_char(logon_time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Logon_Time
  2  from v$process vp, v$session vs
  3  where
  4  vp.addr = vs.paddr and
  5  vs.process in
(select Process
  6    7  from v$session where username in ('SYS','SYSTEM','OPS$ORACLE')
  8  and logon_time >= sysdate-0.010416667
  9  and upper(Program) not like 'ORAAGENT%'
 10  and upper(Program) not like 'EMAGENT%'
 11  and upper(Program) not like 'RMAN%'
and upper(Program) not like 'OMS%'
 12   13  and upper(Program) not like 'YRSUPP%');
```

OUTPUT:

```
SPID                     PROCESS                  LOGON_TIME
------------------------ ------------------------ --------------------
18022440                 22872252                 27-SEP-2013 11:18:01
```

GREP COMMAND SHOULD BE PROCESSED UNTIL $8 VALUE IS EQUAL TO SSHD: THEN SWITCH TO LSOF -I COMMAND:

```
SQL> !ps -ef|grep 22872252
  oracle 18022440 22872252   0 11:18:01      -  0:00 oracleDSPD21 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
  oracle 20119722 22872252   0 11:41:32  pts/1  0:00 grep 22872252
  oracle 22872252 30605374   0 11:18:01  pts/1  0:00 sqlplus

SQL> !ps -ef|grep 30605374
  oracle 20643994 22872252   0 11:41:51  pts/1  0:00 grep 30605374
  oracle 22872252 30605374   1 11:18:01  pts/1  0:00 sqlplus
  oracle 30605374 11993194   0 11:07:31  pts/1  0:00 -ksh

SQL> !ps -ef|grep 11993194
    root 11993194 15925354   0 11:07:31  pts/1  0:00 sudo su - oracle
  oracle 19791924 22872252   0 11:42:08  pts/1  0:00 grep 11993194
  oracle 30605374 11993194   0 11:07:31  pts/1  0:00 -ksh

SQL> !ps -ef|grep 15925354
  oracle 10092584 22872252   0 11:42:29  pts/1  0:00 grep 15925354
    root 11993194 15925354   0 11:07:31  pts/1  0:00 sudo su - oracle
 l061749 15925354 11075676   0 11:07:27  pts/1  0:00 -ksh
```

HERE I GOT SSHD:

```
SQL> !ps -ef|grep 11075676
 l061749 11075676 20447276   0 11:07:27      -  0:00 sshd: l061749@pts/1
 l061749 15925354 11075676   0 11:07:27  pts/1  0:00 -ksh
  oracle 20250734 22872252   0 11:42:57  pts/1  0:00 grep 11075676
```

FOR THE SSHD PROCESS NEED TO USE BELOW COMMAND:

```
SQL> !lsof -i|grep 11075676
lsof: WARNING: can't open /home/oracle/.lsof_ohpr420: Permission denied
sshd      11075676  l061749    3u  IPv4 0xf1000e0007dcb3b8    0t50893  TCP ohpr420.rcc.nsw.westpac.com.au:ssh->10.120.119.76:egptlm (ESTABLISHED)
```

FROM THIS GREP THE IP ADDRESS:

```
SQL> !lsof -i|grep 20447276
lsof: WARNING: can't open /home/oracle/.lsof_ohpr420: Permission denied
sshd      20447276     root    3u  IPv4 0xf1000e0007dcb3b8    0t51813  TCP ohpr420.rcc.nsw.westpac.com.au:ssh->10.120.119.76:egptlm (ESTABLISHED)
```

PLEASE DO THE NEEDFUL.

THANKS AND REGARDS
SURESH

Comment: I've improved the indention of your question but I will  not convert the ALL CAPS to normal English. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I want to pass the output of the sql query to aix command, later the command should grep the processes until the condition met:

Answer (score 0):

On AIX, the lsof command must be run by root, otherwise you will get the "Permission denied" message.

Good article which uses the lsof command. "Who's using my port? (AIX, Linux, Windows example)" from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264632